# Нужна ли запятая перед «ты»?

Tags: пунктуация, обращение

Предложение:
*Раз уж ты начал.*
«Ты» является обращением, надо ли выделять слово запятыми?

Answer (score 1):

Не нужна здесь перед "ты" запятая.
В этом предложении ***ты*** является подлежащим, ***начал*** — сказуемым [ты (что сделал?) начал; начал (кто?) ты], ***раз (уж)*** — подчинительным союзом [= если (уж), коли (уж), ежели (уж)].

Но, как говорится, полезай в кузов, **раз уж ты назвался** грибом! [Борис Хазанов. Плюсквамперфект и другие времена // «Волга», 2008]
Это прозвучало так: отнеси бутылку, **раз уж ты** ни на что более сложное **не способен**. [Фазиль Искандер. Чик и белая курица // «Знамя», 2000]
**Раз уж ты зашел**, проверь, пожалуйста, текст на экране. [Александра Маринина. Последний рассвет (2013)]

[**2. Раз**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7), ***союз**. Разг.* = Если.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно не надо, *ты* никогда не является обращением.

Comment: По академическому словарю «ты» может являться обращением

Comment: Местоимения ты, вы могут выполнять функцию обращения в следующих случаях:
а) при наличии определительных конструкций — обособленных определений или определительных придаточных частей предложения.

б) при самостоятельном употреблении, обычно с междометиями эй, ну, эх, цыц и др. (в разговорной речи):

Comment: Но в моем примере вы правы. Запятые не нужны

Comment: Вот здесь обращение: *Ты, иди сюда.*